# Is there a way to automate the deletion of db2 transaction log files and archive log files when storage filled up to a given level?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400, transaction-log

I do manually the deletion of db2 transaction log files and archive log files when storage filled up to a given level? But I need to automate this. Is there a way or script to automate this?

Comment: Yes, there is, but it depends on the operating-system that runs the Db2-server (Z/OS,  i series(as/400), linux/unix/windows).  So when you ask for help, always tag the Db2 server platform to give that information.

Comment: If the Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, the command is PRUNE , see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001992.html   , but you need to take great care to ensure that you prune only logfiles that are already archived and not needed for recovery or other replications.

Comment: OS is os 400, then what could be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a scheduled script to eliminate unnecessary log files of DB2, for example:

```
find /data/db2/backup/logs/db2inst1/SAMPLE/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/C0000001/*.LOG -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: I used this method with a cronjob and it did my work.